# What is a good log aggregation and error management tool?

Tags: logs

Requirements include . . .

1. Aggregate log data from files, applications, locally, over the network
2. Functionality can be enhanced through plug-ins or other mechanism
3. Can be extended using Go or JavaScript
4. Can extract errors from log data
5. Extracted errors can be handled and resolved as in an issue tracker
6. Provide visualizations of log data

I'm preparing to work on standing up a log aggregation and error monitoring system for multiple servers and applications.  I previously investigated the combination of [Logstash](https://github.com/elasticsearch/logstash) and [Sentry](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry) for this purpose and was planning on implementing it.  However, for a couple reasons, I'd prefer using a [Go](http://golang.org/)-centric solution if there were a comparable one available.

The first reason is the environment.  I'd like to keep things as simple as possible.  We already have Java apps all over the place, so running Logstash wouldn't be a problem.  Sentry, however, would be the only Python application I'd have to support.

The second reason is the language I'd need to use to extend the functionality of these apps.  Since it is likely that I will be extending the functionality of whatever I end up going with by writing plug-ins, for example, I would prefer that whatever I use is either written in or supports plug-ins written in a language I'm more familiar with, such as JavaScript or Go.  Logstash is written in Ruby (jRuby) and Sentry is written in Python.

Some people suggested [Packetbeat](http://packetbeat.com/), [InfluxDB](http://influxdb.com/), and [Grafana](http://grafana.org/).  They look very full-featured and impressive, but it looks like none of those does anything like Sentry does in the way of error management.  In fact, I don't know of any other open-source apps beside Sentry that provide this functionality.  If there were an alternative to Sentry, even if it weren't written in Go, I'd be interested in trying it out.